# Asynchronous Sockets: Server stops receiving due to spam?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

So I have been developing a chat messenger application for a school assignment and I have run into a metaphorical wall.

The application allows you to log in to a sever through a username from which you can initiate chat with other user.

For the most part it is working, it connects and you can send messages however when you try to send consecutive messages it seems like the server ignores the data(as it is sent by the client) even though the sockets are still connected. It will not acknowledge this message until it receives another from client.

This is a video of the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bUV6Ns02sY&feature=youtu.be

I am really dumbfounded and have no idea how to approach this so any and all help is greatly appreciated, if my code is necessary I will post it just tell me to.

Edit: I am aware that this is extremely broad I am just looking for some ideas or approaches I could try and hopefully get me going in the right direction.

Edit 2: 
Server Receive snippet:

```
    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar) //Used to interpret data sent to the Server
            {
                try
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Receiving!");
                    Socket clientSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState; //Pass socket through beginReceive
                    clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);   //Procedure complete

                    //Transform the array of bytes received from the user into an
                    //intelligent form of object Data
                    Data msgReceived = new Data(buffer);

                    //We will send this object in response the users request
                    Data msgToSend = new Data();

                    byte[] message;

                    //If the message is to login, logout, or simple text message
                    //then when send to others the type of the message remains the same
                    msgToSend.cmdCommand = msgReceived.cmdCommand;
                    msgToSend.strName = msgReceived.strName;

                    switch (msgReceived.cmdCommand)
                    {
                        case Command.Login:

                            //When a user logs in to the server then we add them to our
                            //list of clients

                            ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
                            clientInfo.socket = clientSocket;
                            clientInfo.strName = msgReceived.strName;

                            clientList.Add(clientInfo);
                            msgToSend.cmdCommand = Command.List; //Need to send back a list of clients
                            updateServer("<<<" + msgReceived.strName + " is now connected on: " + clientInfo.socket.LocalEndPoint + ">>>");
                            break;

                        case Command.Logout: //Currently not working

                            //When a user wants to log out of the server then we search for them 
                            //in the list of clients and close the corresponding connection

                            int nIndex = 0;
                            foreach (ClientInfo client in clientList)
                            {
                                if (client.socket == clientSocket)
                                {
                                    clientList.RemoveAt(nIndex);
                                    break;
                                }
                                ++nIndex;
                            }
                            clientSocket.Close(100);

                            updateServer("<<<" + msgReceived.strName + " has disconnected>>>");
                            msgToSend.cmdCommand = Command.List;
                            break;

                        case Command.Message:

                            //Set the text of the message that we will broadcast to desired user
                            updateServer(msgReceived.strMessage);
                            msgToSend.cmdCommand = Command.Message;
                            msgToSend.strMessage = msgReceived.strMessage;
                            msgToSend.strName = msgReceived.strName;
                            msgToSend.strCName = msgReceived.strCName; //the recievers name

                            break;

                        case Command.List:

                            break;
                    }

                    //Send the message back to the deisred client
                    if (msgToSend.cmdCommand == Command.Message)
                    {
                        message = msgToSend.ToByte();
                        foreach (ClientInfo client in clientList)
                        {
                            if (client.strName == msgReceived.strCName)
                            {
                                client.socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), client.socket);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Send a list of clients back to the client
                    if (msgToSend.cmdCommand == Command.List)
                    {
                        foreach (ClientInfo client in clientList)
                        {
                            msgToSend.strMessage += client.strName + "*";
                        }
                        msgToSend.strName = null;
                        message = msgToSend.ToByte();
                        foreach (ClientInfo client in clientList)
                        {
                            client.socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), client.socket);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Server - OnReceive", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);


  }
        }
```

Server sending snippet:

```
private void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar) //Callback for BeginSend
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                client.EndSend(ar); //Procedure Complete
                client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), client); //Listens for more commands
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Server - OnSend", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Client Sending Snippet:

```
//Invoked via chat clients and is used to send a message to the server
        public void chat_sendMessage(string name, string contact, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                Data msgToSend = new Data(); //New data structure
                msgToSend.cmdCommand = Command.Message; //Set command to Message as we are sending a message
                msgToSend.strName = name; //Set sender name to parameter value: name
                msgToSend.strMessage = message; //Set strMessage to parameter value: message
                msgToSend.strCName = contact;  //Set reciever Name to parameter value: contact

                byte[] b = msgToSend.ToByte(); //Turn data structure into byte array

                State.workSocket.BeginSend(b, 0, b.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);  //Send using asynchronous socket (State.workSocket)

                if (State.workSocket.Connected == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection Lost :(");
                }

                State.workSocket.BeginReceive(State.buffer,
                                      0,
                                      State.buffer.Length,
                                      SocketFlags.None,
                                      new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                                      State.buffer);   //Listen to incoming data, uses State.buffer to store data
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Login Client - Send Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Data structure used to communicate between server and client:

```
enum Command
    {
        //Log into the server
        Login,
        //Logout of the server
        Logout,
        //Send a text message to all the chat clients     
        Message,
        //Get a list of users in the chat room from the server
        List,
        //Null Value
        Null
    }

    //The data structure by which the server and the client interact with 
    //each other
    class Data
    {
        //Default constructor
        public Data()
        {
            this.cmdCommand = Command.Null;
            this.strMessage = null;
            this.strName = null;
            this.strCName = null;
        }

        //Converts the bytes into an object of type Data
        public Data(byte[] data)
        {
            //The first four bytes are for the Command
            this.cmdCommand = (Command)BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);

            //The next four store the length of the name
            int nameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);

            //The next four store the length of the message
            int msgLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8);

            //The next four store the length of the client Name
            int cnameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 12);

            //This check makes sure that strName has been passed in the array of bytes
            if (nameLen > 0)
                this.strName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 16, nameLen);
            else
                this.strName = null;

            //This checks for a null message field
            if (msgLen > 0)
                this.strMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 16 + nameLen, msgLen);
            else
                this.strMessage = null;

            if (cnameLen > 0)
                this.strCName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 16 + nameLen + msgLen, cnameLen);
            else
                this.strCName = null;
        }

        //Converts the Data structure into an array of bytes
        public byte[] ToByte()
        {
            List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

            //First four are for the Command
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)cmdCommand));

            //Add the length of the name
            if (strName != null)
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strName.Length));
            else
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

            //Length of the message
            if (strMessage != null)
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strMessage.Length));
            else
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

            //Length of the Client Name
            if (strCName != null)
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strCName.Length));
            else
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

            //Add the name
            if (strName != null)
                result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strName));

            //Add the message text to our array of bytes
            if (strMessage != null)
                result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strMessage));

            //And, lastly we add the Client Name to our array of bytes
            if (strCName != null)
                result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strCName));

            return result.ToArray();
        }

        public string strName;      //Name by which the client logs into the room
        public string strMessage;   //Message text
        public string strCName;     //Name of the desired recipient
        public Command cmdCommand;  //Command type (login, logout, send message, etcetera)
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some code snippets that do the reading/sending of your messages? Have you been able to extract this behaviour into a sample program?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Hey, I updated my question with some of the relevant snippets (Sorry they are so long). Unfortunately I have been able to replicate the issue in a sample program, it seems unique to my chat messenger :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making use of the return value of `EndReceive`. it tells you how many bytes were received. Note, that TCP does not preserve messages. Your protocol must give rise to a way to separate them. Look into message framing.

Can your code tolerate all data to be received byte-by-byte or the data of one hour all at once? It must.

Comment: I have added the data standard that I use to read/write messages between client and server, it states the byte length and everything not sure if this is what you were meaning. Sorry for any ignorance.

Comment: Can your code tolerate all data to be received byte-by-byte? Will your code work if Receive returns you one byte at a time?

Comment: @usr +1 because, if it can not, it will be forever unreliable.

Comment: @usr I am actually un-sure how I would go about setting up a test like that, are there perhaps any example projects laying around somewhere?

Comment: @SimonTaylor a simple test would be to split the message that you want to send into two buffers and send them with 1sec sleep in between. Also, just by inspection your code cannot deal with that because it nowhere processes the information how many bytes were received.

Comment: @usr What exactly would I have to do with the byte length because with the constructor I think I can easily extract the byte length of the message. Thank you very much for you help btw :)

Comment: Well, data.Length is not the length of the received data. It is the length of the buffer. But that buffer is likely to have unused space at the end. Try looking into BinaryReader and BinaryWriter in combination with NetworkStream. Those classes automate some of the message framing because internally they keep reading until they have the wanted number of bytes.

Comment: @usr ok I am thinking:
- Check if name is null and if not add the byte length of name
- Check if message is null and if not add the byte length of message
- etc

The where do I put/what do I do with then length

Comment: @usr I have been having a look around, is this what you were referring to? http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html

Comment: Yes. That article looks good. Make sure to understand the underlying issue 100%. You won't be successful with sockets without this understanding.

Comment: @usr Thanks man. I have it working now, you help was very much appreciated :)